# memory allocation in x86 Assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

I was learning about SIZEOF and TYPE operators yesterday. While doing that, I created an array,

```
Array QWORD 1h,2h,3h,4h,5h
```

and in .code section, I wrote,

```
MOV eax, SIZEOF Array
```

After assembling this, it's awkward that I got only 28 bytes allocated for array (using visual studio community 2015). I saw the values of registers in debugging session.

My question here is, each QWORD occupies 8 bytes of memory. Then, why didn't I get SIZEOF Array as 40?

Even worse.
When I run this,

```
Array QWORD 1h
```

it gave me 8 bytes as expected

```
Array QWORD 1h,2h
```

Gives me 10..!!
And,

```
Array QWORD 1h,2h,3h
```

Gives me 18..!!
And so on...

Comment: What is the assembler being used? Tag the post with it. And make titles mor e precise :-)

Answer (score 6):

By default, Visual Studio's register window shows hexadecimal numbers. Could it be that you are confusing 28 with 0x28? 0x28 is the same as 40. (Similarly, 0x10 is 16, 0x18 is 24, and so on.)

Comment: Oh thank you zneak. The registers were set to display hexadecimal. I be changed them now . THANKS..!!

Comment: @Vasanth hex is default, because it allows you to see particular bytes, so by looking at `"12345678"` in `eax` you know the `al` is `0x78`, `ah` is `0x56` and `ax` is `0x5678` ... Try it in decimal... :D

Comment: Thank you.. @Ped7g

Answer (score 0):

It's hexadecimal, obviously. Counting the numbers between the total bytes after adding 1h and 2h, we get 8-9-A-B-C-D-E-F-10. If ye wanna convert decimal to hexadecimal to really get an edge in x86 programming, I would suggest dividing the decimal number by 16 repeatedly, and arranging the remainders in little-endian order to get the big-endian hex numeral (be sure to write A-F for results of 10-15!).